# Ask where to download on Apple Mail

Tags: mail.app, email, data-transfer

I am a new user to Macs. I am finding Apple Mail frustrating because it will only let me download attachments to the Download folder. The preferences do not help either, as that only lets me set a different permanent folder. I do not see an option to ask where to download like there is on chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click or Ctrl/click - Save Attachment…

[image]